# Every finite field can be obtained by a quotient of the ring $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Every finite field can be obtained by a quotient of the ring $\Bbb Z[x]$.

**My try**:

Any finite field $F$ is of the order $p^n$ where $p$ is a prime and $n\in \Bbb N$ .

If we want to make a field of order say $p^n$ then take the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle p \rangle$  and then form the field $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ .

Then choose an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$  and form the quotient $\Bbb Z_p[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle $ and we get a field of order $p^n$ elements.

**Two questions**:

1. Is the result correct?
2. Is my proof correct?

Please help.

Comment: you should probably prove that there is such an irreducible polynomial of degree  $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $F$ be a finite field, $(F-\{0\},\times)$ is cyclic. Let $u$ a generator. Consider the map $g:Z[X]\rightarrow F$ defined by $g(X)=u$.

For your proof, you have to show that there exists $f$ such that $F=Z_p[X]/(f)$

Comment: how do I know that the multiplicative group is cyclic ?

Comment: This a well-known result http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic

Comment: I think http://mathoverflow.net/a/54741/84768 is the most convincing. and how do you know that there is only one field with $p^k$ elements  ?

Comment: I don't know if every finite field can be written as a quotient $Z_p[X]/(f)$ this may be true if $F$ is a separable extension of $Z/p$ since you may apply the primitive element theorem.

Comment: @user1952009, there is no need of knowing that there is only pne field with $p^k$ elements to prove that a finite field has cyclic multiplicative group.

Comment: @Tesmo, the field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is in fact perfect, so every one of its extensions is separable.

Comment: I don't know what your proof is. If you are referring to the one in the question, then no, unless you (a) show that all fields of cardinal $p^k$ are isomorphic and (b) there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$ for all $k$s.

Comment: I did not mean the proof ,I meant the the way of proof ;are they logical enough@MarianoSuárez-Alvarez ;Also please notify me by writing @ when you answer the question